# java pircbot cannot over ride final method from pircbot

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello I have a question about pircbot.  I'm trying to have a send message method but i have an error that i am confused with.

here is my code

```
 import org.jibble.pircbot.PircBot;


 public class sendMessage extends PircBot {


public sendMessage() {
    this.setName("user");
}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {

sendMessage bot = new sendMessage();
bot.setVerbose(true);
bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "oauth:code");
bot.joinChannel("#channel");

public void sendMessage(String target, String message) {
    sendMessage(target, "hello");
}

}
```

it says that cannot over ride final method from pircbot.  I dont understand whats wrong. can someone help me understand why im getting this?

Comment: Looks like you also have an error in your first declaration of `sendMessage()`, you forgot to specify the return time, which from what I gather should be `void`

Comment: Using lowercase names like `sendMessage` for a class confuses the hell out of everybody... Better to stick with common naming conventions and make it `SendMessage`...

Comment: @jangroth +1 you're right, and I did get confused! (leaving the comment so others can see the good point you made).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method declared `final` means that it cannot be overridden. Thus no matter how much you extend the `PircBot`, you can't change that method which has been provided. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html) tutorial for more details on `final`.

Instead of trying to extend the class, consider using composition instead.

Also it looks like you just want to use the `PircBot`, so why not just use it as provided?

```
PircBot bot = new PircBot();
bot.setName("user");
bot.setVerbose(true);
bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "oauth:code");
bot.joinChannel("#channel");
bot.sendMessage(target, message);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method "sendMessage": is trying to Override one of the PircBot Super Class, and is final. You cannot Override a final method. Have a look here [Class PircBot Doc.](http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot.html)

Also, you should consider changing the name of you class "sendMessage" for another one, to don't make confusion with the constructor and the method (equals to the Super class).

Also, the name of your class should be in a pattern of good practice, with the first letter in uppercase. 
Here a example:

```
 public class MyBot extends PircBot {// changed here


    public MyBot() { // changed here
        this.setName("user");
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {

    MyBot bot = new MyBot(); // changed here
    bot.setVerbose(true);
    bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "oauth:code");
    bot.joinChannel("#channel");

    //changed here
    public void sendMyMessage(String target) {
        sendMessage(target, "hello");
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`sendMessage()`](http://(http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot.html#sendMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%20)) in [class `PircBot`](http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot.html) is indeed `final`.

It has the following signature:

```
public final void sendMessage(String target, String message)
```

You did not need to override it at all. You can use it in your code.

```
bot.sendMessage(target, "hello");
```

You still need to provide a `target` String which is defined as follows

> The name of the channel or user nick to send to.